# how to create a database that is suitable for xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have understood the basic concepts of core data and how to create schemas or data model in xcode. However I am struggling to create database and import it xcode.

I don't have any experience with creating databases before.

Can somebody guide me here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is document based, the database is the document. You create it in code when you create the document.

If it's not document based and will use just one single database, then you generally create it in code the first time the application is run (or, more likely, whenever the application is started and it cannot find an already existing database).

In either case if the database can start empty, that's all you need. If an empty database would be invalid and you do need some minimal data when you initialize it, you will have to populate it upon creation.

Depending on how much data your minimal database needs to have you can either hardcode the initialization or use a static resource (that is, a file) in your application bundle containing the initialization data in some form that you know how to read and use that to populate the database.

Comment: Thanks for guiding...will it possible to guide to me to some tutorial link

Comment: Google is your friend. I just googled _core data preload tutorial_ and got pointed to http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated which seems to illustrate both preloading from a known format and writing a companion application that creates a preloaded database that you can then just copy.

Comment: I am looking for a single view based application tutorial where the core data option is not selected in the beginning while creating the project. Raywenderlich tutorial i had come across previously too. Thanks for sharing the information however.

Comment: Tutorial is by definition an example of how to do something. Why would anyone write a tutorial on CoreData by telling you to create a project without checking the core data option? You are not going to find the solution to YOUR problem in the form of a tutorial. You may find tutorials that explain the basics. You have to figure out your solutions by yourself once you understood the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Using SqlLite is more attractive to me as I import the database without any modifications to the android version.

And I made some generic class to handle any database for android and iPhone but I cannot share it here.

```
Class DBWRAPPER
{
    initDB();
    ExecuteScalar()
    ExecuteDicionary();
    Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow-up on the `AnalogFile` answer, in case your application is not document base, you probably want to use core data with a preexisting SQLite DB. You could feed your DB with a scripting language like Python. e.g. I think it is a better approach than populating your DB programmatically in XCode. Check this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data) for more info about this approach.